# Provide parameter to previous screen to refresh in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

I have a use case where I am using a stack navigator to navigate from screen 1 to 2
On screen 2 the user has the option to do some actions. On moving from screen 2 back to 1, I want to check if an action was performed on screen 2 and if yes, refresh the screen 1 Basically I was to pass a kind of doRefresh param from screen 2 back to 1 and refresh screen 1 is doRefresh is true.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  const callback = () => {
    // refresh data here ...
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {callback: callback});
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  /* 2. Get the param */
  const { callback } = route.params;

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => { 
           callback(); // call callback here
           navigation.goBack(); // then navigate back
        } 
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```